# Enviar e-mail após uma mudança no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou utilizando o banco de dados MySQL  e tenho um evento que é executado diariamente a 1 hora. Dentro desse evento eu verifico a data presente em uma linha e comparo com a data atual, caso a data atual seja menor então faço as operações necessárias. O problema é que eu preciso enviar um e-mail indicando que essa operação ocorreu. É possível chamar uma função do PHP para realizar esse trabalho a partir do evento MySQL?

```
    function daily_situation_update()
   {
    global $wpdb;
    $mapping = get_option('socialdb_general_mapping_collection');
    $collection_id = $mapping['Emprestimo'];
    $event = "CREATE 
        EVENT IF NOT EXISTS
         e_daily_situation_update
        ON SCHEDULE
          EVERY 1 DAY_HOUR 
        COMMENT 'Altera o Status dos livros'
        DO
          BEGIN 
            SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
            UPDATE
                $wpdb->term_relationships
            SET
                term_taxonomy_id = ...
```

Comment: Como você está executando esta tarefa diária? Cron?

Comment: Criei um evento no MySQL pra realizar essa tarefa, criei o evento a partir do PHP

Comment: Então, por favor, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar esses códigos. Se você já possui o PHP envolvido nesse processo, não deve ser difícil fazer ele enviar o e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que com isso você já possa mandar email :
    
       
          Envio de Email via PHP

```
   <body>

      <?php
         $to = "emailPara@umDominioQualquer.com";
         $subject = "Assunto do Email";

         $message = "<b>Mensagem HTML</b>";

         $header = "From:emailDe@umDominioQualquer.com \r\n";
         $header .= "Cc:copiaCarbono@umDominioQualquer.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Sucesso...";
         }else {
            echo "Algo deu errado...";
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Referencia : [Fonte do Exemplo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm)

Comment: O problema não é mandar um e-mail usando PHP e sim mandar esse e-mail apenas quando o evento do MySQL fizer modificações em determinada coluna.

Comment: Acredito que podes fazer um 'if' para validar a variavel $event, se for o resultado esperado = envia o email, se não for, processe da forma que quiser ... Algo neste sentido.